# Why there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|\leq m^*(E)+\varepsilon$.

Tags: measure-theory

Why for all $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ there is a cover $E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$ of closed cube such that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|\leq m^*(E)+\varepsilon$$

I know that $$m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|\mid E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\right\}$$
where $Q_i$ are closed cube. So I by the property of the infimum it's clear that if $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\supset E$ such that $$m^*(E)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|\leq m^*(E)+\varepsilon,$$
but the question is why such a cover $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\supset E$ exist ? If my question is not clear, tell me.

Comment: Are you assuming that $E$ is bounded? Otherwise you might have some issues.

Comment: No I don't suppose $E$ bounded.

Comment: If $E$ is not bounded how do you interpret $\infty+\epsilon$? Actually bad question you don't need to require $E$ is bounded. It's enough that $m^*(E)$ is finite.

Comment: I think the correct approach would be to point if $E$ is unbounded and the sum turns out to diverge for all covers then the inequalities are trivially true (assuming $\infty\leq\infty+\epsilon$. Otherwise $m^*(E)$ is finite and so there is at least one cover (since the inf was not infinite) and you're also done.

Comment: By the continuum property of $\mathbb{R}$ every non-empty appropriately bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an infimum / supremum. 

Suppose, **for the sake of argument**, that $E$ only had two covers of the appropriate from, call them $A,B$ then $m^* (E) = min \{m^*(A),m^*(B) \} $. 

We're just playing around with defintions here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm under the impression that you are mixing up things a bit.

i) You almost certainly don't want to find an $\varepsilon > 0$ with this property, but you want, for any *given* $\varepsilon > 0$ find a family of cubes such that your statement becomes true.

ii) the $\inf$ in the definition of $m^*(e)$ is the infimum over all families of cubes covering $E$. So in fact, by the definition, you will find such a cover.

Edit: if the value of $m^*(e) $ is $ \infty $ note that $ \infty + $ any finite value is just $ \infty $ .

(2nd Edit: the question was modified after I wrote this answer, so i) does not make sense any more, but I won't write the answer from scratch.... )

Comment: i) Yes, I corrected it. Sorry. ii) But why is there such a cover ? It's what I don't understand. For example, if I set $A=\inf\{k\mid k^2<-1\}$, since $k^2<-1$ has no sense, for an $\varepsilon>0$ we won't have a $k^2$ such that $A<k<A+\frac{1}{2}$. So if $\varepsilon>0$ why can I find a $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\supset E$ such that $$m^*(E)<\sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|< m^*(E)+\varepsilon \ ?$$ Is my question more clear ?

Comment: @rick but in that example you are trying to get something else. In your OP what you need is a cover. You always get some countable cover by closed cubes due to separability. The sum of the sizes might be divergent but if it is for all such covers then $m^*(E)$ is $\infty$ and thus the original question (with $\leq$'s instead of $<$) works.

Comment: Your $A$ is empty, so every set covers it.

Comment: His $A$ is not a set. It's a number. It's a broken analogy.

Comment: When you say:  "the inf in the definition of $m^∗(e)$ is the infimum over all families of cubes covering E. **So in fact, by the definition, you will find such a cover.**" You will find such a cover if there exist such a covering. And I think, it's what the OP want's to prove: that there exist a covering of closed cube.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ a bounded set and $\varepsilon>0$. The set $$\mathcal O=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid d(x,E)<\varepsilon\right\}$$
is an open set that contain $E$. Moreover, all open set of $\mathbb R^n$ can written as a countable union of almost disjoint closed cube, i.e. $$\mathcal O=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$$ where $Q_i$ are closed cube almost disjoint (i.e. $\text{int}(Q_i)\cap\text{int}(Q_j)=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$).

Therefore, you can always approche $E$ by a countable union of closed cube.

Comment: If you can always approche any set $E$ by a countable union of closed cube, what is the difference between a mesurable set and a not mesurable set ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by difference between measurable and not measurable set ? Even a mesurable set is not necessarily a countable union of closed set (take for example Cantor set).